# git clone from Azure DevOps returns "No such device or address" error

Tags: git, azure

I use batch script below to clone the git project from Azure DevOps to local, where "1234" is the PAT generated from "Repos > Files > Clone button > Generate Git Credentials button"

```
git clone https://1234@dev.azure.com/test/test_project
```

It works at the beginning. But after sometime it returns error below.

```
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: Verification code expired before contacting the server
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://1234@dev.azure.com/test/test_project/_git/test_project': No such file or directory
```

Would anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/auth-overview?view=azure-devops I wonder if you need to use a different authentication method?

Comment: `fatal: Verification code expired before contacting the server` is the actual error. Everything *after* this is merely additional problems cascading down because of the initial failure. That's pretty common in automated systems (though so are warnings and other messages that come *before* the actual failure, so never assume too much!).

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a

> [`AADSTS70019`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes)    CodeExpired - Verification code expired. Have the user retry the sign-in.

Using a [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows) should be more effective. You can control its expiration date.